# QLogic BCM57800 gets no link

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I am running a Dell PowerEdge 820 with a QLogic (Formerly Broadcom) NetXtreme II BCM57800 NIC. It has 4 ports and I am using the first fibre optics port. This card is controlled by the bnx2x kernel driver.

Currently the system is running SuSE Linux Enterprise 11 SP4 and everything works fine. (Kernel 3.0.101-108.21-default, bnx2x driver 1.710.51-0)

For various reasons I would like to switch to Ubuntu (16.04). Sadly the network interface does not work properly anymore. The driver gets loaded and detects everything correctly, but I get no link.
(Kernels 4.4.0-87-generic and 4.4.0-112-generic, bnx2x driver 1.712.30-0)

Here is an excerpt from the syslog

```
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.120328] bnx2x: QLogic 5771x/578xx 10/20-Gigabit Ethernet Driver bnx2x 1.712.30-0 (2014/02/10) 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.125393] bnx2x 0000:01:00.0: msix capability found
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.130376] bnx2x 0000:01:00.0: part number 394D4342-30383735-30305430-473030 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.272109] bnx2x 0000:01:00.1: msix capability found 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.272479] bnx2x 0000:01:00.1: part number 394D4342-30383735-30305430-473030 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.424153] bnx2x 0000:01:00.2: msix capability found 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.424501] bnx2x 0000:01:00.2: part number 394D4342-30383735-30305430-473030 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.572040] bnx2x 0000:01:00.3: msix capability found 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.579253] bnx2x 0000:01:00.3: part number 394D4342-30383735-30305430-473030 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.707381] bnx2x 0000:01:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.729537] bnx2x 0000:01:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth1 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.765642] bnx2x 0000:01:00.3 eno4: renamed from eth3 
Feb 16 08:05:38 ubuntu kernel: [    5.805490] bnx2x 0000:01:00.2 eno3: renamed from eth2 
Feb 16 08:06:06 ubuntu kernel: [   41.310371] bnx2x 0000:01:00.0 eno1: using MSI-X  IRQs: sp 56  fp[0] 58 ... fp[7] 65 
Feb 16 08:06:06 ubuntu kernel: [   41.526277] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
```

When I boot the SuSE everything works fine again. I updated the NIC firmware in several steps from 7.2 to 14.02.12 with no effect. I also tried ubuntu 17.10 without success (driver version is identical)

Any ideas how to proceed?